Updating to latest version of ngx-bootstrap
I have an Angular project that uses Bootstrap 3.4.1. I can't update it to 4 or 5 since it will break all the styles.
I'm also using ngx-bootstrap in the project. After updating to Angualr 17, I can't update ngx-bootstrap to latest since it does not support Bootstrap 3.
What is the best option I have in this scenario ?

Inform the stakeholders about this problem and protect yourself, tell that upgrade is not possible without updating bootstrap styles. since bootstrap 4 is not backwards compatible and proceeeding with the upgrade is risky

You can't update ngx-bootstrap without upgrading to bootstrap 4/5, meaning your choices are limited to a) Not updating ngx-bootstrap, or b) Updating both ngx-bootstrap and bootstrap.
